# affiliate in iframe, jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, ads

Does an affiliate site work when I display it in an iframe? On my website I have an ad link of a partner. I want to display it in an iframe, that is wrapped by an jquery dialog. The user should be able to use the partner site in the dialog just as a normal website and to shopping ...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES it will no problem whatsoever